# How to invoke a function, whose name is passed in Json object?

Tags: javascript, json, callback

I have a JSON object with a key element called callback.

```
{
"id":34,
"description":"",
"item_id":4,
"callback":"addNew",
"filename":"0000072.doc",
"type":"News",
"ext":"doc",
"size":46592
}
```

I would like to call the javascript "addNew" function. I tried.

```
json.callback(json);
```

But does not work. Any idea?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Assuming it is a global function (it shouldn't be):

```
window[json.callback](json);
```

If your code is well structured you will probably have an object containing all the functions the JSON could call.

```
var myObject = {
  func1: function myObject_func1_method(foo) {
    return 1;
  },
  func2: function myObject_func2_method(foo) {
    return 2;
  }
}
```

Then you can:

```
myObject[json.callback](json);
```

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for, but I don't see that the functions need to be named.  You will be calling the functions using the func1, func2 identifiers, so the names myObject_func1_method and myObject_func2_method seem entirely unnecessary.  Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 9):

Don't use eval, use

```
window[json.callback](json);
```

If the function is in the global scope. Use the scope instead of window otherwise.

Answer (score -2):

Use `eval(json.callback+'()');`

Comment: Come on! Two minus votes. The guy tried to help! i vote you one up!

Comment: He may have tried, but he advised poorly. This is not just a poor answer, it's downright dangerous and should be downvoted accordingly.

Comment: Thanks Sergio for your comment. Sorry if my solution wasn't good.

Comment: @Garry +1 - The tooltips for the votes use the term "helpful" not "effort".

Comment: Me and @Thinker did not know about the danger of eval. So his answer and both @David Dorward's and @Fabien Ménager's answers helped us to learn about it. So, Thinker's answer brought some value. 

It is clear which answers are more correct  (+11 or +9 vs -1), so I do not see any need to punish him with minus votes.I think punishing so hard only discourage users to provide answers.